# AutoHotKey & Steam Overlay Interaction

Tags: overlay, autohotkey, autorun, steam

Might already be answered but here we go. I wanted to write an AutoRun script using AutoHotKey for DayZ. It basically consists of two keys being constantly pressed and then slept. Easy script. But I want it to do one more thing. I want to be able to shift tab in the standalone to the web browser and still autorun while browsing say, facebook. Is there any way this can be possibly done? Thanks in advance.

Would probably help if I pasted the script to make it more concise.

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
#IfWinActive, DayZ
lctrl::
Send {w Down}
Send {lshift Down}
W::Sleep
return
```

Super simple. Basically the only issue, as I said, is that when I use the steam overlay to shift + tab to the browser, my keypresses, and therefore, autorun macro, doesn't persist. I am not sure if there's any way to remedy this but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use control send, to send keys to inactive windows. See here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm

Comment: So, did it work for you? If so, please accept an answer to mark this as Resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Your keys don't persist because they depend on DayZ being active. When the steam overlay is active, well the game is no longer active.

Use [ControlSend](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm), to send keys to inactive windows.

See the following example:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
lctrl::
ControlSend, , {w Down}, DayZ
ControlSend, , {lshift Down}, DayZ
W::Sleep
return
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a god. I'll give that a try. Let you know what happens with it.